# Combinations and Outcomes Confusion (PMF)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, combinations

I have added a resource I found online. There are no answers just notes.[image]

My understanding is that the coin is tossed 4 times and we are asking what is the probability that the random variable X is equal to x=2? In this case, 2 Heads.

But 
a. Where is the actual probability? I guess you would need the full PMF to know this?
b. Does the answer of 6 (n=4 choose=2) tell us that there are 6 outcomes where there are 2 Heads? And the probability of there being 2 Heads with n=4 would just be the amount of outcomes here(x=2)/total number of outcomes? 
c. How do we figure out how many possible combinations in total there are with 4 tosses? (including where there are not two heads?) Sometimes I get confused between Simple Counting and Combinations.

Comment: You may have a clear idea what problem it is you want help with, but you've presented it in a rather confusing way.  The lead sentence talks about a resource you "found online" without any link to that, and you say, "There are no answers just notes."  Readers are given little idea from the huge image posted under that what you wanted to ask about.  Please consider editing your Question to fully pose the problem (the setup and goal) that Readers should be trying to respond to.

Answer (score 1):

I will attempt to give a better explanation to the steps to find the probability. Perhaps this will help answer your three questions you have listed.

To start, there are $2×2×2×2 = 16$ possible outcomes for flipping a coin four times. This can be easily seen by the fact that each flip has two possibilities. To find the number of these outcomes that have two heads, we need to realize we need to *choose* $2$ out of the $4$ to be heads. If you are familiar with combinatorics, it is clear that the number of ways is $\binom{4}{2} = 6$. **However**, to say the probability of two heads in four flips is $6/16$ just from this information alone would be incorrect if we are dealing with a weighted or biased coin.

If the probability of flipping a head is $p$, then obviously the probability of tails must be $1-p$. Then the probability of flipping two heads in four flips must involve a product of $p^2$ and $(1-p)^2$, to account for two heads and two tails. And we cannot forget that there are $6$ ways to flip two heads in four flips, so our factor of $6$ must also be involved. This leads us to the formula you have described: $$\binom{4}{2} p^2 (1-p)^2$$.

If we do not have a a specified value for $p$, then this is as far as we can get aside from algebraic manipulation. With a specific $p$ between $0$ and $1$, we can simplify to a single number to represent the probability.

Notice that if we have a standard, unbiased coin, then our probability of heads would be a $0.5$, and by plugging in this $p$ we will get our $6/16$ from earlier.

Comment: I get 3/8 from doing the math in the last paragraph of yours,,, the reduced form..that is still correct, right?

Comment: Yes, this works as all you are doing is simplifying the fraction

Comment: btw, how would we need to change this formula if the weightings are different?